# C programming help - adding values together/for loop

Tags: c, loops

I'm trying to add values together that I get using a for loop but I'm stumped as to how to do it.  This is the code I have so far:

```
    float counter;
    float harmonic;
    float sum;

    for (counter = 2; counter <= n; counter ++)
    {
        harmonic = 1/counter; // current value
        sum = harmonic; // stores current value                          
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So basically for each value I get for the "harmonic" variable I need to add it to the next until the loop ends.  Should I be looking at arrays?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all you should do is use `sum = sum + harmonic;` instead just assigning it. You would use arrays only if you need to keep the complete list of single values.

Comment: btw: Question is off topic here and will most likely be migrated to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to read

```
float sum = 0;
```

then inside the loop write

```
sum += harmonic;
```

You don’t need an array unless you want to remember all of the values you’ve summed.

Also, don’t use a `float` as your loop counter.  You probably want an `int` instead.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help guys, really appreciate it. :]  @alastair I used a float for counter as the calculations do not come out right if I make it an int.  Not sure why this happens.. I'm using codeblocks on lubuntu btw

Comment: @stevesy you can use `int` for counter, but then use `harmonic = 1.0 /counter`. It's always better to give `int` value for any counter.

Comment: @Arjun thanks a lot, yes I found out that's exactly what I needed to do.  Still trying to get my head round it fully - I'd assumed that if harmonic was a float then it wouldn't matter whether counter was an integer i.e. that harmonic would just give a decimal answer. Obviously not : ]

Comment: @stevesy: if both operands to the `/` operator are integers, then the result is an integer value, so `1/counter` will come out as `0` when `counter` > 1; this result will be converted to a float on assignment.  If you need the result of the division to have a floating-point type, then at least one of the operands needs to be floating-point; in this case, using `1.0` is the right answer.